# How can I obtain a NY LLC Biennial Statement?

Tags: public-domain, foia, public-records

In New York, limited liability corporations are [required to file biennial reports](https://www.wolterskluwer.com/en/solutions/bizfilings/state-guides/new-york-llc-requirements).

Are these biennial reports public documents, and if so, how can a member of the public get a copy of an LLC's biennial reports?

Answer (score 2):

The report, or at least the information contained in the report (not necessarily an image of the document actually filed) is available [here](https://apps.dos.ny.gov/publicInquiry/).